# two values are seemingly the same, yet matlab says the aren't

Tags: matlab

I cannot explain this. I have two variables having the same value, yet they are not identical. Can anybody tell me what I'm missing here?

```
>> y
y =
3.4000
>> x
x =
3.4000
>> y==x
ans =
 0
>> whos x
 Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes
 x         1x1                 8  double              
>> whos y
 Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes
 y         1x1                 8  double
```

It's really puzzling for me and I swear it's not a joke.

Comment: try format long; before printing

Comment: You may want to read this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 5):

It's because of floating point precision. Try

```
format long g
```

and then look at `x` and `y` again. It's better to compare `x-y` to some small tolerance value  rather than doing an equality test on floating point numbers

Comment: See also http://matlab.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#Why_is_0.3_-_0.2_-_0.1_.28or_similar.29_not_equal_to_zero.3F

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing float values, an activity which doesn't work quite how you think in basically any language, due to how floating-point values are handled by computers.

The solution to this is generally to instead test whether the different between the values is less than some small threshold.

See [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/66553) for a Matlab-related discussion of this.