# Matlab comparation of two numbers not working

Tags: matlab, if-statement, for-loop

I'm trying to compare three numbers in a if statement but they don't match even if they are the same.

here are the numbers from the command window,

```
>> a = (round2(final_aucscore(10, 1),1e-4))

a =

    0.9369

>> b = (round2(final_aucscore(10, 2),1e-4))

b =

    0.9598

>> c = (round2(final_aucscore(10, 3),1e-4))

c =

    0.9509
```

the function `round2` can be found in the file echange [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4261-round2).

here's my code:

```
for mmm = 1:265

    a = (round2(final_aucscore(mmm, 1),1e-4));
    b = (round2(final_aucscore(mmm, 2),1e-4));
    c = (round2(final_aucscore(mmm, 3),1e-4));
    if   a == 0.9369 && b == 0.9598 && c == 0.9509
        auc_idx = idx(1:kk);
        save('auc_idx', 'auc_idx', 'mmm');
        break;
    end
end
```

shouldn't it stop and save when `mmm = 10`?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877576/

Comment: That `round2` function on the FEX is terrible (and even has a 4.8 rating!). It's not even vectorized. *Such things should not be allowed.* It could be replaced by this anonymous function: `round2 = @(x,y)round(x./y).*y;` or you could edit the code. However, it's still going to be subject to the imprecision of floating-point.

Comment: [This function on the FEX](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6077-round2), also called `round2`, appears to be much more numerically sound (only rated 4.3 though...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're facing here comes from rounding error.
Try this

```
foo = 0.9369;
bar = (round2(foo,1e-4));
disp(bar == foo)
disp(foo-bar)
```

You could instead make a function to compare only within a certain precision.

Answer (score 2):

[What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) Read it and weep.